# Html modal popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using following code to display the html modal popup window. It is showing absolutely fine. Only problem is that one of the fields in my div is Date time filed and i am using jquery datetimepicker module. But when i click on the calendar image the calendar drop down is displaying in the main HTML page not on the popup html page. Can any one have a look in to my code and give me suggestion on what i am doing wrong here.

```
  <div id="shade" ></div>
  <div id="modal">
      <label> Summary:   </label>
      <input type="text" name="summary" id="summary" style="width: 500px;"/>  <br>
      </select><br>
      <label> priority:  </label>
      <select id="change_type" name="change_type" style="width: 150px;">
          <option value ="Minor"> Minor</option>
          <option value ="Medium"> Medium</option>
          <option value ="Major"> Major</option>
      </select> <br>
      <label> Due Date:   </label>
      <input type="text" name="duedate" id="duedate" value="{{ request.args['duedate'] }}" align ="center" ondblclick="value=''"/>
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='cal.gif')}}" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('duedate','yyyymmdd','dropdown',true,'24')"/><br>

      <button id="id" style="position: absolute;left:600px;">Please verify</button>
      <button id="Cancel" onclick="" style="position: absolute;left:700px;">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

and my ajax call is

```
  $('#cm').blur(function(){
    var cmnumber = document.forms['myform']['cm'].value;
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var shade = document.getElementById('shade');

    $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    data:cmnumber,
    success: function(data) {

            if ( data == cmnumber)
            {  alert ("Its a valid CM")}
            else
            { var answer = confirm("This is Not a Valid CM. Do you want to File a new one?")
                if(answer)
                {
                    modal.style.display=shade.style.display= 'block';
                }
            }

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stack assignments (`=`) like this in JavaScript:

```
 modal.style.display=shade.style.display= 'block';
```

You're already using jQuery, so use:

```
$('#modal, #shade').show()
```